# ¿Cómo actualizar ventana Python Tkinter después del .mainloop()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, msdos

Estoy creando un programa que simule la pantalla del MS-DOS. Esta funciona con etiquetas cuadradas **tkinter.Label()** que cambian de color y así simulan píxeles. Me he quedado atascado en la parte del cursor, en la cual quiero que los píxeles de una zona de la pantalla se vuelvan blancos y luego negros en un bucle infinito hasta que el usuario escriba un carácter. En el código he desarrollado unas cuantas funciones que sirven para imprimir caracteres según la zona donde se empiece a escribir el carácter

Esto no sé como hacerlo, ¿alguna idea?

Código (sin documentar):

```
import time
import tkinter
from tkinter import font
filas=40
columnas=51
pixels=[]
w=tkinter.Tk()
start_c=1
start_r=1
fuente=font.Font(family="Helvetica",size=1)
def main():
    create_pixels(pixels)
    layout_window(w)

    draw("ABD ABD BAD DAB")

    w.mainloop()
def create_pixels(pixels):
    for fila in range(0,filas):
        lista_fila=[]
        for columna in range(0,columnas):
                lista_fila.append("#000000")
        pixels.append(lista_fila)
def layout_window(window):
    global pixels
    global fuente
    for numero_fila,lista_fila in enumerate(pixels):
        for numero_columna,entrada_columna in enumerate(lista_fila):
            square=tkinter.Label(window,text="  ",font=fuente,bg=entrada_columna)
            square.grid(row=numero_fila,column=numero_columna)
def change_color(columna,fila,color,window):
    global pixels
    global fuente
    square=tkinter.Label(window,text="  ",font=fuente,bg=color)
    square.grid(row=fila,column=columna)
    pixels[fila][columna]=color
def draw(string):
    global start_c,start_r
    letters={"A":draw_A,"B":draw_B,"C":draw_C,"D":draw_D}
    for i in string:
        if start_c>=columnas-1:
            start_r+=6
            start_c=1
        if i in letters:
            letters[i](start_c,start_r)
        elif i==" ":
            draw_space()
def draw_A(s_c,s_r):
    global start_c,start_r
    change_color(s_c,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+1,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+2,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+3,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+1,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+2,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+3,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+4,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+3,s_r+1,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+3,s_r+2,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+3,s_r+3,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+3,s_r+4,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+1,s_r+2,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+2,s_r+2,"#ffffff",w)
    start_c+=5
def draw_B(s_c,s_r):
    global start_c,start_r
    change_color(s_c,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+1,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+2,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+3,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+4,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+1,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+2,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+3,s_r+1,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+2,s_r+2,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+3,s_r+3,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+1,s_r+4,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+2,s_r+4,"#ffffff",w)
    start_c+=5
def draw_C(s_c,s_r):
    global start_c,start_r
    change_color(s_c,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+1,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+2,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+3,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+1,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+2,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+3,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+4,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+1,s_r+4,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+2,s_r+4,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+3,s_r+4,"#ffffff",w)
    start_c+=5
def draw_D(s_c,s_r):
    global start_c,start_r
    change_color(s_c,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+1,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+2,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+3,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+4,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+1,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+2,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+3,s_r+1,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+3,s_r+2,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+3,s_r+3,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+1,s_r+4,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+2,s_r+4,"#ffffff",w)
    start_c+=5
def draw_space():
    global start_c,start_r
    start_c+=5
main()
```

Comment: Por favor, añade el código que has intentado hasta ahora para que algún compañero pueda ayudarte de la mejor manera posible. Gracias

Comment: El problema es que es muchísimo código

Comment: Gracias por compartirlo, que sea muy extenso, mientras esté bien estrucuturado y justificado en que se comparta no hay ningún problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No puedes usar ciclos infinitos en una GUI ya que eso bloquea el mainloop y después de la llamada al mainloop no tiene sentido hacer nada, en este punto la interfaz no existe.

La forma más simple de hacer animaciones en el caso de tkinter es usar el método `after`. Dicho método recibe como primer argumento el tiempo en milisegundos tras el que se llevará a cabo la llamada del callable pasado como segundo argumento. El resto de argumentos que se pasen serán pasados directemtne al callble como argumentos.

Eso si, debes asegurate que la función que hace la animación no es bloqueante en si misma.

Te dejo un ejemplo muy simple:

```
import tkinter as tk


DELAY = 500

def update_cursor():
    if cursor["fg"] == "black":
        cursor.config(fg="#3ADF00")
    else:
        cursor.config(fg="black") 
    cursor.after(DELAY, update_cursor)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")
root.config(bg="black")
tk.Label(
    root, text="C:", fg="#3ADF00", bg="black", font=("Courier", 15)
    ).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
cursor = tk.Label(root, fg="#3ADF00", bg="black", text=" ▌", font=("Courier", 15))
cursor.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
cursor.after(0, update_cursor)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En tu caso, la idea es exactamente la misma, puedes hacer algo como:

```
CURSOR_DELAY = 500

def draw_cursor(color="#ffffff"):
    global start_c, start_r
    change_color(start_c, start_r, color, w)
    change_color(start_c, start_r+1, color, w)
    change_color(start_c, start_r+2, color, w)
    change_color(start_c, start_r+3, color, w)
    change_color(start_c, start_r+4, color, w)
    next_color = "#000000" if color == "#ffffff" else "#ffffff"
    w.after(CURSOR_DELAY, draw_cursor, next_color)
```

El código completo:

```
import time
import tkinter
from tkinter import font


CURSOR_DELAY = 500
filas=40
columnas=51
pixels=[]
w=tkinter.Tk()
start_c=1
start_r=1
fuente=font.Font(family="Helvetica",size=1)

def main():

    create_pixels(pixels)
    layout_window(w)
    draw_cursor() # Solo una llamda al inicio de la gui

    draw("ABD ABD")
    draw(" ")
    draw("BAD DAB")

    w.mainloop()

def create_pixels(pixels):
    for fila in range(0,filas):
        lista_fila=[]
        for columna in range(0,columnas):
                lista_fila.append("#000000")
        pixels.append(lista_fila)

def layout_window(window):
    global pixels
    global fuente
    for numero_fila,lista_fila in enumerate(pixels):
        for numero_columna,entrada_columna in enumerate(lista_fila):
            square=tkinter.Label(window,text="  ",font=fuente,bg=entrada_columna)
            square.grid(row=numero_fila,column=numero_columna)

def change_color(columna,fila,color,window):
    global pixels
    global fuente
    square=tkinter.Label(window,text="  ",font=fuente,bg=color)
    square.grid(row=fila,column=columna)
    pixels[fila][columna]=color

def draw(string):
    global start_c,start_r
    letters={"A":draw_A,"B":draw_B,"C":draw_C,"D":draw_D}
    for i in string:
        if start_c>=columnas-1:
            start_r+=6
            start_c=1
        if i in letters:
            letters[i](start_c,start_r)
        elif i==" ":
            draw_space()

def draw_A(s_c,s_r):
    global start_c,start_r
    change_color(s_c,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+1,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+2,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+3,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+1,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+2,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+3,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+4,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+3,s_r+1,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+3,s_r+2,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+3,s_r+3,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+3,s_r+4,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+1,s_r+2,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+2,s_r+2,"#ffffff",w)
    start_c+=5

def draw_B(s_c,s_r):
    global start_c,start_r
    change_color(s_c,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+1,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+2,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+3,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+4,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+1,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+2,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+3,s_r+1,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+2,s_r+2,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+3,s_r+3,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+1,s_r+4,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+2,s_r+4,"#ffffff",w)
    start_c+=5

def draw_C(s_c,s_r):
    global start_c,start_r
    change_color(s_c,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+1,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+2,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+3,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+1,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+2,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+3,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+4,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+1,s_r+4,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+2,s_r+4,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+3,s_r+4,"#ffffff",w)
    start_c+=5

def draw_D(s_c,s_r):
    global start_c,start_r
    change_color(s_c,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+1,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+2,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+3,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c,s_r+4,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+1,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+2,s_r,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+3,s_r+1,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+3,s_r+2,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+3,s_r+3,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+1,s_r+4,"#ffffff",w)
    change_color(s_c+2,s_r+4,"#ffffff",w)
    start_c+=5

def draw_space():
    global start_c,start_r
    change_color(start_c,start_r,"#000000",w)
    change_color(start_c,start_r+1,"#000000",w)
    change_color(start_c,start_r+2,"#000000",w)
    change_color(start_c,start_r+3,"#000000",w)
    change_color(start_c,start_r+4,"#000000",w)
    start_c+=5

def draw_cursor(color="#ffffff"):
    global start_c, start_r
    change_color(start_c, start_r, color, w)
    change_color(start_c, start_r+1, color, w)
    change_color(start_c, start_r+2, color, w)
    change_color(start_c, start_r+3, color, w)
    change_color(start_c, start_r+4, color, w)
    next_color = "#000000" if color == "#ffffff" else "#ffffff"
    w.after(CURSOR_DELAY, draw_cursor, next_color)


main()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: De nada @ByRussX, he modificado el código final, tenía un bug del que no me percaté, dado que el espacio lo "dibujabas" solo cambiando la columna actual, el cursor quedaba dibujado. Debes siempre dejar la columna del cursor en negro para evitar ésto, con los caracteres no hay problema pero si con el espacio. No se si se me habrá escapado algo más, pero cualquier cosa no dudes en comentar. Un saludo.